# ImportError dll load failed the specified module could not be found (rasterio)

Tags: python, rasterio, dll

I want to use the rasterio package to make some test with the Planet Explorer Api (https://www.planet.com/docs/guides/quickstart-ndvi/). I've seen on many forums that I needed to use a wheel file to install rasterio (and gdal), it worked for gdal but for rasterio I got this issue :

```
>> import rasterio
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Users\Hortense\Miniconda3\envs\envpythonfs\Lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  from rasterio.__base import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: the module specified can't be found.
```

I create a virtual environnement with conda, with the version python 2.7, I used those files from this site http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/

GDAL‑2.1.3‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

rasterio‑1.0a9‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

I also download the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008, but it doesn't work either.
I don't know how to solve this, can someone help me ?

Comment: Don't mix conda and Gohlke packages. Try `conda create -n envpythonfs python=2.7 rasterio gdal` or `activate envpythonfs` then `conda install rasterio gdal`.If that doesn't work, use `-c conda-forge` in either of those commands to use the Conda Forge channel.

Comment: Luke's comment has the right answer: because Rasterion is a C extension module, you have to stick with a single Python distribution system and you can't mix packages from different systems.